# How to remove manual installation of Python 3.6.2 without removing Python 3.5 or causing damage?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python3

I installed the Python 3.6.2 that can be downloaded from https://python.org/, but it's causing some trouble with the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` instruction, which now uses 3.6 by default when I need it to use 3.5, since that is the version that has a bunch of libraries I need installed and pip3 still installs everything to 3.5.

The thing is, as I said, I installed it manually, and what could be worse, I did it with `sudo make install` instead of `sudo make altinstall`, so I don't know if Python 3.5 has been partially replaced or something.

Is there any way to remove Python 3.6 in these conditions? Alternatively, is there any way to get `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to use Python 3.5, and to just forget about 3.6?

`#!/usr/bin/env python3.5` works for using Python 3.5, and Python 3.5 can still be opened in the terminal, so I'd like to think I didn't mess with it, but I don't know.

Comment: Look at `ls -l /usr/bin/python3*` - if `/usr/bin/python3` is just a symlink, you may be able tosimply point it at `python3.5`

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get remove python3.6 anyway?

Comment: What's the output of `which python3 python3.5 python3.6 | xargs -rd '\n' -- ls -l --`?